# How can I make my Typo3 copy find its subpages?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, typo3, typo3-10.x

I copied a full Typo3 webpage and its database to a new server to create a testing environment. The login and backend works, all pages and contents have successfully imported aswell. The start page shows the usual content too.

However Typo3 is unable to find the subpages of the start page. When I try to open one of the subpage links, Apache throws a not found exception.

It might be caused by the .htaccess file, which I copied from the live server aswell, however I have no idea what I would be searching for there.
Other than that I have no clue what could cause this.

I tried reinstalling the typo3_src-10.4.6 folder to no avail.

Page tree:

[image: Page tree]

URL Segment of the subpage fachkraefte (which I cannot reach at x.x.x.x/fachkraefte):

[image: URL Segment]

.htaccess:

```
#####
#
# Example .htaccess file for TYPO3 CMS - for use with Apache Webserver
#
# This file includes settings for the following configuration options:
#
# - Compression
# - Caching
# - MIME types
# - Cross Origin requests
# - Rewriting and Access
# - Miscellaneous
# - PHP optimisation
#
# If you want to use it, you have to copy it to the root folder of your TYPO3 installation (if its
# not there already) and rename it to '.htaccess'. To make .htaccess files work, you might need to
# adjust the 'AllowOverride' directive in your Apache configuration file.
#
# IMPORTANT: You may need to change this file depending on your TYPO3 installation!
#            Consider adding this file's content to your webserver's configuration directly for speed improvement
#
# Lots of the options are taken from https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/.htaccess
#
####


### Begin: Compression ###

# Compressing resource files will save bandwidth and so improve loading speed especially for users
# with slower internet connections. TYPO3 can compress the .js and .css files for you.
# *) Uncomment the following lines and
# *) Set $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['compressionLevel'] = 9 for the Backend
# *) Set $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['compressionLevel'] = 9 together with the TypoScript properties
#    config.compressJs and config.compressCss for GZIP compression of Frontend JS and CSS files.

#<FilesMatch "\.js\.gzip$">
#       AddType "text/javascript" .gzip
#</FilesMatch>
#<FilesMatch "\.css\.gzip$">
#       AddType "text/css" .gzip
#</FilesMatch>
#AddEncoding gzip .gzip

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
        # Force compression for mangled `Accept-Encoding` request headers
        <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
                <IfModule mod_headers.c>
                        SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
                        RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
                </IfModule>
        </IfModule>

        # Compress all output labeled with one of the following media types.
        #
        # (!) For Apache versions below version 2.3.7 you don't need to
        # enable `mod_filter` and can remove the `<IfModule mod_filter.c>`
        # and `</IfModule>` lines as `AddOutputFilterByType` is still in
        # the core directives.
        #
        # https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_filter.html#addoutputfilterbytype

        <IfModule mod_filter.c>
                AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \
                        application/javascript \
                        application/json \
                        application/ld+json \
                        application/manifest+json \
                        application/rdf+xml \
                        application/rss+xml \
                        application/schema+json \
                        application/vnd.geo+json \
                        application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
                        application/x-font-ttf \
                        application/x-javascript \
                        application/x-web-app-manifest+json \
                        application/xhtml+xml \
                        application/xml \
                        font/eot \
                        font/opentype \
                        image/bmp \
                        image/svg+xml \
                        image/vnd.microsoft.icon \
                        image/x-icon \
                        text/cache-manifest \
                        text/css \
                        text/html \
                        text/javascript \
                        text/plain \
                        text/vcard \
                        text/vnd.rim.location.xloc \
                        text/vtt \
                        text/x-component \
                        text/x-cross-domain-policy \
                        text/xml
        </IfModule>

        <IfModule mod_mime.c>
                AddEncoding gzip svgz
        </IfModule>
</IfModule>

### End: Compression ###



### Begin: Browser caching of resource files ###

# This affects Frontend and Backend and increases performance.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>

        ExpiresActive on
        ExpiresDefault                                      "access plus 1 month"

        ExpiresByType text/css                              "access plus 1 year"

        ExpiresByType application/json                      "access plus 0 seconds"
        ExpiresByType application/ld+json                   "access plus 0 seconds"
        ExpiresByType application/schema+json               "access plus 0 seconds"
        ExpiresByType application/vnd.geo+json              "access plus 0 seconds"
        ExpiresByType application/xml                       "access plus 0 seconds"
        ExpiresByType text/xml                              "access plus 0 seconds"

        ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon              "access plus 1 week"
        ExpiresByType image/x-icon                          "access plus 1 week"

        ExpiresByType text/x-component                      "access plus 1 month"

        ExpiresByType text/html                             "access plus 0 seconds"

        ExpiresByType application/javascript                "access plus 1 year"
        ExpiresByType application/x-javascript              "access plus 1 year"
        ExpiresByType text/javascript                       "access plus 1 year"

        ExpiresByType application/manifest+json             "access plus 1 week"
        ExpiresByType application/x-web-app-manifest+json   "access plus 0 seconds"
        ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest                   "access plus 0 seconds"

        ExpiresByType audio/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType image/bmp                             "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType image/gif                             "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType image/jpeg                            "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType image/png                             "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType image/svg+xml                         "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType image/webp                            "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType video/mp4                             "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType video/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType video/webm                            "access plus 1 month"

        ExpiresByType application/atom+xml                  "access plus 1 hour"
        ExpiresByType application/rdf+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"
        ExpiresByType application/rss+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"

        ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject         "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType font/eot                              "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType font/opentype                         "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf                "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType application/font-woff                 "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff               "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType font/woff                             "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType application/font-woff2                "access plus 1 month"

        ExpiresByType text/x-cross-domain-policy            "access plus 1 week"

</IfModule>

### End: Browser caching of resource files ###


### Begin: MIME types ###

# Proper MIME types for all files
<IfModule mod_mime.c>

        # Data interchange
        AddType application/atom+xml                        atom
        AddType application/json                            json map topojson
        AddType application/ld+json                         jsonld
        AddType application/rss+xml                         rss
        AddType application/vnd.geo+json                    geojson
        AddType application/xml                             rdf xml

        # JavaScript
        AddType application/javascript                      js

        # Manifest files
        AddType application/manifest+json                   webmanifest
        AddType application/x-web-app-manifest+json         webapp
        AddType text/cache-manifest                         appcache

        # Media files

        AddType audio/mp4                                   f4a f4b m4a
        AddType audio/ogg                                   oga ogg opus
        AddType image/bmp                                   bmp
        AddType image/svg+xml                               svg svgz
        AddType image/webp                                  webp
        AddType video/mp4                                   f4v f4p m4v mp4
        AddType video/ogg                                   ogv
        AddType video/webm                                  webm
        AddType video/x-flv                                 flv
        AddType image/x-icon                                cur ico

        # Web fonts
        AddType application/font-woff                       woff
        AddType application/font-woff2                      woff2
        AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject               eot
        AddType application/x-font-ttf                      ttc ttf
        AddType font/opentype                               otf

        # Other
        AddType application/octet-stream                    safariextz
        AddType application/x-bb-appworld                   bbaw
        AddType application/x-chrome-extension              crx
        AddType application/x-opera-extension               oex
        AddType application/x-xpinstall                     xpi
        AddType text/vcard                                  vcard vcf
        AddType text/vnd.rim.location.xloc                  xloc
        AddType text/vtt                                    vtt
        AddType text/x-component                            htc

</IfModule>

# UTF-8 encoding
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
        AddCharset utf-8 .atom .css .js .json .manifest .rdf .rss .vtt .webapp .webmanifest .xml
</IfModule>

### End: MIME types ###



### Begin: Cross Origin ###

# Send the CORS header for images when browsers request it.
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
                <FilesMatch "\.(bmp|cur|gif|ico|jpe?g|png|svgz?|webp)$">
                        SetEnvIf Origin ":" IS_CORS
                        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=IS_CORS
                </FilesMatch>
        </IfModule>
</IfModule>

# Allow cross-origin access to web fonts.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
        <FilesMatch "\.(eot|otf|tt[cf]|woff2?)$">
                Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

### End: Cross Origin ###

### Begin: Rewriting and Access ###

# You need rewriting, if you use a URL-Rewriting extension (RealURL, CoolUri).

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

        # Enable URL rewriting
        RewriteEngine On

        RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}     !^443$
        RewriteRule (.*)  https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

        # Store the current location in an environment variable CWD to use
        # mod_rewrite in .htaccess files without knowing the RewriteBase
        RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ([^#]*)#(.*)\1$
        RewriteRule ^.*$ - [E=CWD:%2]

        # Rules to set ApplicationContext based on hostname
        #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.example\.com$
        #RewriteRule .? - [E=TYPO3_CONTEXT:Development]
        #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^staging\.example\.com$
        #RewriteRule .? - [E=TYPO3_CONTEXT:Production/Staging]
        #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
        #RewriteRule .? - [E=TYPO3_CONTEXT:Production]

        # Rule for versioned static files, configured through:
        # - $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['versionNumberInFilename']
        # - $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['versionNumberInFilename']
        # IMPORTANT: This rule has to be the very first RewriteCond in order to work!
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(php|js|css|png|jpg|gif|gzip)$ %{ENV:CWD}$1.$3 [L]

        # Access block for folders
        RewriteRule _(?:recycler|temp)_/ - [F]
        RewriteRule fileadmin/templates/.*\.(?:txt|ts)$ - [F]
        RewriteRule ^(?:vendor|typo3_src|typo3temp/var) - [F]
        RewriteRule (?:typo3conf/ext|typo3/sysext|typo3/ext)/[^/]+/(?:Configuration|Resources/Private|Tests?|Documentation|docs?)/ - [F]

        # Block access to all hidden files and directories with the exception of
        # the visible content from within the `/.well-known/` hidden directory (RFC 5785).
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "!(^|/)\.well-known/([^./]+./?)+$" [NC]
        RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
        RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
        RewriteRule (?:^|/)\. - [F]

        # Stop rewrite processing, if we are in the typo3/ directory or any other known directory
        # NOTE: Add your additional local storages here
        RewriteRule ^(?:typo3/|fileadmin/|typo3conf/|typo3temp/|uploads/|favicon\.ico) - [L]

        # If the file/symlink/directory does not exist => Redirect to index.php.
        # For httpd.conf, you need to prefix each '%{REQUEST_FILENAME}' with '%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}'.
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
        RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:CWD}index.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>

# Access block for files
# Apache < 2.3
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        <FilesMatch "(?i:^\.|^#.*#|^(?:ChangeLog|ToDo|Readme|License)(?:\.md|\.txt)?|^composer\.(?:json|lock)|^ext_conf_template\.txt|^ext_typoscript_constants\.txt|^ext_typoscript_setup\.txt|flexform[^.]*\.xml|locallang[^.]*\.(?:xml|xlf)|\.(?:bak|co?nf|cfg|ya?ml|ts|typoscript|tsconfig|dist|fla|in[ci]|log|sh|sql(?:\..*)?|sqlite(?:\..*)?|sw[op]|git.*|rc)|.*~)$">
                Order allow,deny
                Deny from all
                Satisfy All
        </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
# Apache ≥ 2.3
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        <If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#(?i:/\.|/\x23.*\x23|/(?:ChangeLog|ToDo|Readme|License)(?:\.md|\.txt)?|/composer\.(?:json|lock)|/ext_conf_template\.txt|/ext_typoscript_constants\.txt|/ext_typoscript_setup\.txt|flexform[^.]*\.xml|locallang[^.]*\.(?:xml|xlf)|\.(?:bak|co?nf|cfg|ya?ml|ts|typoscript|tsconfig|dist|fla|in[ci]|log|sh|sql(?:\..*)?|sqlite(?:\..*)?|sw[op]|git.*|rc)|.*~)$#">
                Require all denied
        </If>
</IfModule>

# Block access to vcs directories
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 404 /\.(?:git|svn|hg)/
</IfModule>

### End: Rewriting and Access ###



### Begin: Miscellaneous ###

# 404 error prevention for non-existing redirected folders
Options -MultiViews

# Make sure that directory listings are disabled.
<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
        Options -Indexes
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
        # Force IE to render pages in the highest available mode
        Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge"
        <FilesMatch "\.(appcache|crx|css|eot|gif|htc|ico|jpe?g|js|m4a|m4v|manifest|mp4|oex|oga|ogg|ogv|otf|pdf|png|safariextz|svgz?|ttf|vcf|webapp|webm|webp|woff2?|xml|xpi)$">
                Header unset X-UA-Compatible
        </FilesMatch>

        # Reducing MIME type security risks
        Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
</IfModule>

# ETag removal
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header unset ETag
</IfModule>
FileETag None

### End: Miscellaneous ###


# Add your own rules here.
```

Comment: First I'd have a look if the links of menus are correct. If they use another domain than your testing domain, the problem is in your installation itself and not primarily related to .htacess.

Comment: Could be that it's not possible to access pages below a sysfolder. Try to change the sysfolder into a normal page (maybe with hidden in menu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically a httpd 404 means that TYPO3 wasn't triggered, so your htaccess/Rewrite rules aren't working. This could be a lot of reasons, most probably

- that the Apache has the Rewrite module not installed or
- that the Apache config forbids the htaccess from being used.

(This is under the assumption that you get your URLs from a navigation rendered via TYPO3 on the main page. If that is not the case, it could be that the new server renders umlauts differently, too; always use a navigation for those tests.)

Comment: It works now! I had to install the rewrite module and alloc htacces in the config. There was a problem with the .htaccess file aswell: I had to comment the lines RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}     !^443$ and RewriteRule (.*)  https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]